Is it possible to monitor the memory utilisation of a zone when setting nginx rate limit?
For example, if you set the
limit_req_zone $uri zone=product:1m rate=30r/s;
I understand that it allows up to 30 identical URIs per second and stores them in the 1M memory space to distinguish between unique URIs. Here I can store about 16,384 in 1M memory.
I've encountered the following error due to a problem with the memory space and not the rate setting.
"could not allocate node in limit_req zone"
I'm testing under load to reproduce this, but is it possible to monitor memory space using rate limit in nginx?
